# How to set the text of an element with Dart?

Tags: javascript, html, dart

I realize my first helloworld 3days ago, and now I wana go futher.

I try to call a function, and put the result in my html.

My HelloWorld.dart

```
import 'dart:html';

main() {
  var s = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    s = '$s$i ';
  }

  HTMLElement element = document.getElementById('text');
  element.innerHTML = 'test';
  //element.innerHTML = s;
  print(s);
}
```

My print(S) Work, it print me in my Output of dart Editor : 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

But now, I want to put the result in my html.

So this is my HelloWorld.html :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HelloWorld</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="HelloWorld.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Exercice 01</h1>

    <p>Hello world from Dart!</p>

    <div id="container">
      <p id="text"></p>
    </div>

    <script type="application/dart" src="web/HelloWorld.dart"></script>
    <script src="https://dart.googlecode.com/svn/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/client/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Pretty simple isn't? So actually I see my page with my h1 and my p. BUT, i dont see anything in my id "text", i try to push my var s, doesn't work, so I try to push a simple string as you can see (return at the first block of code of my post), and doesn't work.

I probably missunderstood something for communication between .html and .dart, can some one help me please?

Ps :  I dont have any error in my Output .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks for the question!

First, use `querySelector()` instead of document.getElementById, like this:

```
import 'dart:html';

main() {
  var s = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    s = '$s$i ';
  }

  var element = querySelector('#text');
  element.text = 'test';
  print(s);
}
```

querySelector() works by accepting a CSS selector and returning the first element that matches. To find an element by ID, use `#the-id` syntax (or, prefix the element's ID with a `#`).

Instead of `innerHTML`, use `element.text` setter.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Be mindful of updated syntax; These days you will want to use 'querySelector' to acquire elements by ID, and 'querySelectorAll' to acquire a collection of elements, such as by their common class name.